# How to configure certificate for downloadable server software

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

I write downloadable software that, when installed and run, starts (amongst other things) a Jetty web server (on port 3220, if that matters, I think not) serving up web pages.

I want to serve a page on the web site over HTTPS. This page collects credit card information that is sent directly to Stripe. My understanding is that technically I don't have to serve this over HTTPS because the page talks directly to Stripe and no CC details hit my own servers, but I want to serve this over HTTPS to get the padlock "warm and fuzzies".

My understanding is that to do this I need to purchase a certificate; a self signed certificate won't do because the browser will show a warning. I want to distribute the certificate with the software so the user can just install and go. However, the certificate, when created, needs to include the hostname. I obviously don't know the hostname of the user's computer before they've even installed and run the software.

So how can I purchase and distribute a certificate without knowing the hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to get such a certificate. The hostname wouldn't be qualified with a domain, and no CA is going to sign a certificate for '`*`'. Also, some browsers (definitely Chrome) would complain about such a certificate ('You are connected to a server with a name only valid within your network').

You could consider redirecting the user to a server you control on the public internet (with a proper certificate), just for the credit card part of the application.